# Find phone numbers with a missing 0

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a csv file opened in Notepad++ and try to use the Search/Replace function with "Regular Expression" checked to find phone numbers with a missing 0.

I have started my regular expression as `(\d[0-9]{10})` which finds all phone numbers, but I just need to find those with a missing leading 0.

What is the appropriate RegEx pattern to do this, please?

---

Test data of the csv file:

```
ID,TITLE,FNAME,SNAME,GENDER,PHONE,MOBILE,DOB,
1,Mrs,Sue,Mac,Female,01702 11000,07961111111,23/4/1958 
01,Mrs,Sue,Mac,Female,1702 11000,07961111111,23/4/1958 
2,Mr,Jim,Bell,Male,01698502269,07961111111,5/5/1958 
3,Mr,John,Smith,Male,,,,,,,,17/5/1958 00:00:00
4,,Batman,Smith,,,,,,,01389 111 111,07961111111,29/5/1958      
04,,Batman,Smith,,,,,,,1389 111 111,07961111111,29/5/1958      
5,Mr.,Hulk,Smith,Male,01389 111 111,07961111111,2/6/1958 
6,Mr.,Hulk,Briggs,Male,21,07961111111,6/6/1958 
06,Mr.,Hulk,Briggs,Male,21,7961111111,6/6/1958 
7,Mr.,Mike,Brigs,Male,15-20,07961111111,6/6/1958 
8,Mr.,Mike,Briggs,Female,20,07961111111,6/6/1958 
9,Mr,David,Golden,Male, 01254 111111,07961111111,10/6/1958
10,Mr,Pete,Lee,Male,020 7111 1111,07961111111,22/6/1958 
11,Ms,Karren,Lee,Female,02881111111,07961111111,4/7/1958 
12,Ms,Lisa,Bond,Female,,,,,,01411111100,07961111111,16/7/1958 
13,Mr,Murdasa,Smith,Male,01268 000 000,07961111111,20/7/1958 
14,,Brian,Smith,,(0)1753 604000,07961111111,24/7/1958 
15,,Brian,Smith,,12 (0)1753 604000,07961111111,24/8/1958 
015,,Brian,Smith,,12 ()1753 604000,07961111111,24/8/1958
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to match even fewer than 11 symbols. 
You can use `(?<=,)\b[1-9][0-9 ]{3}[ 0-9]{6,}` regex to get your phone numbers.

These lines are matched:

- 01,Mrs,Sue,Mac,Female,`1702 11000`,07961111111,23/4/1958
- 04,,Batman,Smith,,,,,,,`1389 111 111`,07961111111,29/5/1958
- 06,Mr.,Hulk,Briggs,Male,21,`7961111111`,6/6/1958

Comment: I want to find the phone numbers which have a missing 0 at the front of the number.  E.g. i want to find 1702 11000 which is the row of ID 01 from the test data sample

Comment: @RiazLadhani: I think I have got it right, please check the new regex.

Answer (score 4):

You should replace `\d` (any digit) with `[1-9]` (any digit **but** 0).

If I got you right, the RegEx pattern you need is: `\b([1-9](\d *){9})\b`, you can adjust the `{9}` to `{8,10}`, depending on the desired phone number length.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/6MHprAW.png]

**EDIT**: Added word boundaries (`\b`) and let the pattern ignore inbound whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing boundary hence you get all first 10 digits of your 11-digit numbers.

Try (\b[0-9]{10}\b)

but this will find the phone number for Mr. Hulk Briggs and that has nothing do to if there is a 0 in the number or not.

Not sure if your question is correct. Are you looking for numbers that don't start with the 0-digit? Are you looking for any number that does not have a zero at all?

Comment: I am looking for numbers that don't start with a the 0-digit.  e.g. Mrs,Sue at row id 01.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"Not a zero" is `[1-9]`, but it's not as simple as just using that because some of your phone numbers have spaces, and you need to make sure you don't start the match part way through a number.

Try this:

```
(?<=,)[1-9][0-9 ]{8,10}(?=,)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/6IgUJIt7fZ).

This matches between commas (but not including them) and allows the length of the number to be from 9 to 11 (you can adjust that easily by changing the length range).

Comment: Is this syntax correct for Perl5, Notepad++?  In Notepad++  I get the error Can't find the text (?<=,)[1-9][0-9 ]{8,10}(?=,)  when i run it in Notepad++

Comment: Have you ticked the "Use regex" option?

Comment: I added a link showing it working with your sample data. If there are any target numbers it failed to match, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A regex which detects all the phone numbers in your test sample which lack a leading 0 is:

```
\b(?<!\(0\))[1-9](?: ?\d){8,9}\b
```

Or in commented form:

```
\b            (?# detect leading word boundary)
(?<!\(0\))    (?# confirm that it is not preceded by parenthesized 0)
[1-9]         (?# detect a non-zero digit)
(?: ?\d){8,9} (?# detect 8-9 digits, each possibly preceded by a space)
\b            (?# detect trailing word boundary)
```